# Azure Search - exact match as first or single result

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Search based on the rich Lucene Query Parser syntax. I defined to "~1" as additional parameter to one symbol for distance ). But I faced with problem, that the entity is not ordered even if there is exact match. (For example,"blue~1" would return "blues", "blue", "glue". Or when searching product SKU like "P002", I would get result "P003", "P005", "P004", "P002", "P001", "P006" ) 
So my question: is there some way to define, that the entity with exact match must be first in list, or be singl search result even then I'm using fuzzy search "~1"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [Lucene Query syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt589323.aspx) you can boost individual subqueries, for example: `term^2 | term~1` - this translates to "find documents that match 'term' OR 'term' with edit distance 1, and score the exact matches higher relative to fuzzy matches by a factor of two.

`search=blue^2|blue~1&queryType=full`

There is no guarantee that the exact match will always be first in the results set as the document score is a [function of term frequency and inverse document frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). If the fuzzy sub-query expands the input term to a term that's very unique in your document corpus you may need to bump the boosting factor (2 in my example). In general, relying on the relevance score for ordering is not a practical idea. Take a look at my answer in the following post for more information: [Azure Search scoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814079/azure-search-scoring)

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks! That works, but I made only one difference: as I understood, the "OR" operator will get results "blue^2" OR "blue~1" OR BOTH. So as you said there is no guarantee that the exact match will always be first. After some experiments I've achived a "strict or" by doing search=(blue^2)|(blue~1)&queryType=full