# Azure Cognitive Search: search query with two search profiles

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, fuzzy-search

Our search service uses Azure Cognitve Search in the following way:

1. Search non-fuzzy (i.e. with full match of query string).
2. Search fuzzy (i.e. it's allowed to change 1-2 letters in a query string)
3. Join results by certain rule.

This way we want to achieve that full match results will always be on the top.

But now we want to introduce a pagination. And to do it with two separate queries is a difficult and not effective task.
An alternative would be to somehow create a single query which will combine in itself both fuzzy and non-fuzzy search but with different scoring profiles, one with higher weights for full-match search and another with lower weights for fuzzy search.
Like
`search=rabbit&scoringProfile=highWeightsProfile | seacrh=rabbit~&scoringProfile=lowWeightsProfile`

Is there any way to do this, either in API or in SDK?
Is there any other alternative solutions to the problem of fuzzy search but with higher scores for full-match?

Answer (score 0):

[Boosting individual subqueries with Lucene query syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771652/azure-search-exact-match-as-first-or-single-result) worked for me as a good solution. Maybe not that flexible as separate search profiles for fuzzy and non-fuzzy parts, but still good.