# Is it possible to change the scoring profile based on the number of tags?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a document with a collection of strings representing the number of times that document appears in a region (tags). For example:

```
[{
  "id": "A"
  // other properties
  "regions": ["3", "3", "3", "2"] // Appears 3 times in region "3" and once in region "2"
},
{
  "id": "B"
  // other properties
  "regions": ["3", "3", "1"] // Appears twice in region "3" and once in region "1"
}]
```

I tried using a custom scoring profile of type `Tag`, but I don't see how to give documents with more regions a better score. In other words, I want `document A` that appears 3 times in `region 3` to show before `document B` that only appears twice in `region 3`.

FYI, the reason we chose to represent regions this way is because there are way too many regions and not all documents appear in all regions. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292188/azure-search-order-by-dynamic-data)

Is this doable? This way or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag scoring profile checks for an existence of a tag. If the tag appears multiple times, it has no effect on the score.

I've read your other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292188/azure-search-order-by-dynamic-data). One solution you could consider (which is not exactly what you want) is to bucket the regions based on count. For example, you'd have a collection of regions where the document shows up less than 10 times, between 10 and 50, between 50 and 100 (pick the ranges in a way that make sense for the distribution of region occurrences in your scenario). You're documents would look like this:

```
{
  "id": "A"
  "regions10": ["3", "2"] // Appears in region 3 and 2 less than 10 times
  "regions50": ["1"] // Appears in region 1 between 10 and 50 times
}
```

Then, you could use a Weights scoring profile to boost documents that matched in the higher count regions:

```
 "scoringProfiles": [  
    {  
      "name": "boostRegions",  
      "text": {  
        "weights": {  
          "regions10": 1,  
          "regions50": 2,  
          "regions100": 3  
        }  
      }  
    }
```

This is not a good solution if you need strict ordering based on the region count, you can't precompute the region counts, or the entire range of value is large (say 0 to 2^31) while the individual buckets need to be small (you'd end up with too many fields).

The problem you have is a data modeling problem. You're trying to retrieve documents based on the property of the document, which is whether it contains a region in a set of regions, but score/boost the document based on the properties of the region, not the document. You'd have to have a document in the index for each document-region pair an a property with the number of times given document appeared in that region.

Comment: I've read somewhere that you are working on Complex Data Type support and that is in private beta at the moment. Would Complex Data Types help me in this regard? Something like `"regions": [ {"1": 45}, {"2": 32} ]`